# Centos Linux to Oracle Linux Conversion

Tags: centos, oraclelinux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnThU.png)

centos version 8

Here in the above image, trying centos Linux to Oracle Linux.
while I'm executing the command "sudo bash centos2ol.sh"

getting a message "You appear to be running an unsupported distribution" and terminating the execution. as it is in the image.

Now, how to execute the centos2ol.sh file ???

Comment: Use a "supported" distribution (you will need to research what that means) and if you cannot work it out then follow the instructions on your screen and ask for assistance through opening an issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are running Centos Stream, which the centos2ol.sh script does not support, per the [README](https://github.com/oracle/centos2ol). You can verify this in the file

```
/etc/os-release
```